# Craft CMS 3 create custom field in plugin with two fields returning two values

Tags: templating, craft3, field

I need to get two text fields under the same custom form and have it return two different values to be stored in the database.  Right now with what I have, it's storing the same variable for both, which I get why it's happening, but I can't come up with a viable solution to return two values.

setting the field

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Value 1',
    instructions: 'test',
    name: name,
    style: 'width: 50%',
    value: value})
}}
{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Value 2',
    instructions: 'test',
    name: name,
    style: 'width: 50%',
    value: value})
}}
```

Field function:

```
public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
{
    return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('custom-plugin/cloudinary_field',
        [
                'name' => $this->handle,
                'value' => $value,
                'field' => $this,
        ]
    );
}
```

How can I make these two text fields each return a value to be stored in the database?

Comment: You can store an array in your DB as json. Would that be enough or do you need a custom table in order to enable advanced searching/filtering?

Comment: I believe that would work, but I'm hitting a wall trying to figure out how to use it as an array.

Comment: I've got the json arrays working, however I can't get the two fields to store the data in craft when we hit save.  I believe it's because the input fields both have the same name.  I'd assume these field names need to be unique?  I found https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/more-than-one-field-for-a-fieldtype-plugin which mentions the defineContentAttribute function, but it does not appear to be available in craft 3.